# CSS: Flexible box goes over edge of element

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I'm a big fan of the flexible boxes in CSS3, but I have a situation where they're behaving a bit weird. Within an `<li>`, I have a text and a time that I want to display next to each other:

```
<li>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
    <time>10:25</time>
</li>
```

This time should be aligned to the right. Some simple CSS should suffice.

```
#flexbox li {
    display: flex;
}
#flexbox li time {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

For the most part if works just fine, but when the text gets a bit bigger...

[image]

As you can see, it crosses the edge of my containing `<div>`. I've created [a Plnkr that demonstrates this.](http://plnkr.co/edit/GyYWUAGSiydKoi2mgwKs?p=preview). Just to try something, I've added a `word-wrap: break-word`, but (as expected) nothing changed.

I noticed that the effect is less when using Firefox, but still crossing the boundary of the containing element. It seems to a browser bug though. Using Chrome 35 and Firefox 30 (the current latest versions). Any ideas how to best deal with this?

As always, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm, I would have thought applying `justify-content: space-between;` would get the desired result, but the `time` element still gets pushed out. It's computed width of ~15px is not enough to accommodate it, so it is bleeding out. You can fiddle with its width, but it probably isn't something you want to hardcode.

Comment: Indeed. In my current situation it's workable to hardcode the width, but no doubt I'll run into this again sometime in the future where that solution won't hold up. Nice tip on the `justify-content` approach though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the cases in which the `time` overflows, I noticed that the `spans`'s are sized a little wider than the text they contain. Here is an image to show what I mean: http://linenwoods.com/images/capture.png

As I understand, the width of flex items should be based on the content they contain (which *is* the case for the flex items that have less text). I observed that adding `flex: 1 1 0;` to the `span`'s [fixes](http://plnkr.co/edit/iztX1OJZrFvWC9oU9DfN?p=preview) this inconsistency, but I still don't understand why it's needed.

```
#flexbox li span {
   flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Haha I'm as amazed as you are. `margin-left: auto;` is method #1, `justify-content: space-between` is method #2, and `flex: 1` is a third approach to this challenge. And for whatever reason, that last one seems to do the trick. Cross-browser too. Still no idea why the first two don't work as they should, but still: Well done :-)

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add `flex:none` to your `time` rule, to prevent it from shrinking (which is what's really happening when its text overflows).

It shrinks because both flex items (the `<span>` and the `<time>`) start out at their preferred sizes and then cooperatively grow or shrink from there -- and the `<span>`s with a lot of text are very greedy. Each `<span>`'s preferred size is the *length of all of its text, laid out on a single line*. For the large `<span>`s, that clearly doesn't fit, so *both* flex items are shrunk until they fit. (Since the `<time>` starts out much smaller, it shrinks less -- but it does shrink a bit.)

If you use `flex:none` on `<time>`, then that sets its `flex-shrink` property to 0, which prevents that item from shrinking at all. Then, the `<span>` is forced to do all the growing/shrinking, which is what you want.

(NOTE: in the future, this won't actually be necessary, because the flexbox spec now has a default [minimum width for flex items](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/#min-size-auto) which would prevent `<time>` from shrinking in this case.  That was only added (back) to the spec recently, though, so browsers haven't caught up yet.)